# Employee standard object is not visible in App launcher using sandbox org

Tags: administration, standard-objects, work.com

i want information about the employee standard object. I am using sandbox org and i cant find employee object in app launcher so how can i enable visibility of this object?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_employee.htm) regarding permissions for this Workplace object?

Comment: Yes i checked all the permissions according to the documentation but still it's not visible in app launcher.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you create tab of that object and ensure Deployment Status is set to Deployed.
Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000330223&type=1

Comment: Since Employee is a standard object, the tab should already exist and can't be created.

Comment: yes right david..employee is a standard object so no need to create a tab for that.